# Module Error Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, heroku, twitter

I am working on twit API. My code working very fine in local (node bot.js) but when i upload my files to Heroku its not working.It saying module "twit" not found !
This is my code :

```
console.log("Bot is running !");
const Twit = require("twit");
const config = require("./config");
const twit = new Twit(config);
const stream = twit.stream("user");
const operation = {
  "doTwit" : msg => {
    twit.post('statuses/update',
    { status: msg },
    (err, data, response) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("An Error Occured !" + err.message);
      } else {
        console.log("Successfully tweeted !");
    }
  });
},
"sendMessage" : (id, name, msg) => {
  twit.post(
    "direct_messages/new",
    {
      user_id : id,
      screen_name : name,
      text : msg
    },
    (err, data, res) => {
      if (err) {
        operation.sendMessage(807594238535868421, "designer_sohail", err.message);
        console.log("An Error Occured !" + err.message);
      }
    }
  );
}
}
stream.on("follow", e => {
  operation.sendMessage(e.source.id, e.source.screen_name, `Thanks for 
  following me. How are you ${e.source.screen_name}!`);
});
stream.on('favorite', e => {
  operation.sendMessage(e.source.id, e.source.screen_name, `Thanks for favouriting my tweet! ${e.target_object.text.slice(0,25)} ...`);
})
```

Inside my Procfile I puted "worker: node bot.js"
Inside my config file

```
module.exports = {
  consumer_key: "values",
  consumer_secret: "values",
  access_token: "values",
  access_token_secret: "values"
}
```

These are the build logs from Heroku
I clicked on the latest build and copied from there
:

```
      Node.js app detected
  Creating runtime environment

   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
   NODE_VERBOSE=false
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
  Installing binaries
   engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
   engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

   Resolving node version 8.x...
   Downloading and installing node 8.9.4...
   Using default npm version: 5.6.0
   Restoring cache
   Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
   - node_modules (exists - skipping)
   - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
   Building dependencies
   Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
   Rebuilding any native modules
   ajv@5.5.2 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/ajv
   co@4.6.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/co
   fast-deep-equal@1.0.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/fast-deep-equal
   fast-json-stable-stringify@2.0.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/fast-json-stable-stringify
   json-schema-traverse@0.3.1 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/json-schema-traverse
   asn1@0.2.3 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/asn1
   assert-plus@1.0.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/assert-plus
   asynckit@0.4.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/asynckit
   aws-sign2@0.7.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/aws-sign2
   aws4@1.6.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/aws4
   bcrypt-pbkdf@1.0.1 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/bcrypt-pbkdf
   tweetnacl@0.14.5 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/tweetnacl
   bluebird@3.5.1 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/bluebird
   boom@4.3.1 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/boom
   hoek@4.2.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/hoek
   caseless@0.12.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/caseless
   combined-stream@1.0.5 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/combined-stream
   delayed-stream@1.0.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/delayed-stream
   core-util-is@1.0.2 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/core-util-is
   dashdash@1.14.1 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/dashdash
   ecc-jsbn@0.1.1 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/ecc-jsbn
   jsbn@0.1.1 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/jsbn
   extend@3.0.1 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/extend
   extsprintf@1.3.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/extsprintf
   forever-agent@0.6.1 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/forever-agent
   form-data@2.3.1 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/form-data
   mime-types@2.1.17 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/mime-types
   mime-db@1.30.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/mime-db
   getpass@0.1.7 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/getpass
   har-schema@2.0.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/har-schema
   har-validator@5.0.3 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/har-validator
   hawk@6.0.2 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/hawk
   cryptiles@3.1.2 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/cryptiles
   boom@5.2.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/cryptiles/node_modules/boom
   sntp@2.1.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/sntp
   http-signature@1.2.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/http-signature
   jsprim@1.4.1 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/jsprim
   json-schema@0.2.3 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/json-schema
   verror@1.10.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/verror
   sshpk@1.13.1 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/sshpk
   is-typedarray@1.0.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/is-typedarray
   isstream@0.1.2 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/isstream
   json-stringify-safe@5.0.1 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/json-stringify-safe
   oauth-sign@0.8.2 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/oauth-sign
   performance-now@2.1.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/performance-now
   punycode@1.4.1 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/punycode
   qs@6.5.1 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/qs
   request@2.83.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/request
   safe-buffer@5.1.1 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/safe-buffer
   stringstream@0.0.5 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/stringstream
   tough-cookie@2.3.3 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/tough-cookie
   tunnel-agent@0.6.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/tunnel-agent
   uuid@3.1.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/uuid
   twit@2.2.9 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/twit
   mime@1.6.0 /tmp/build_2fd6e2dc3b700b830abe821f30d7c86b/node_modules/mime
   Installing any new modules (package.json)
   removed 55 packages in 0.632s
   Caching build
   Clearing previous node cache
   Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
   - node_modules
   - bower_components (nothing to cache)
   Build succeeded!
   Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types     -> worker
   Default types for buildpack -> web
   Compressing...
   Done: 17.3M
   Launching...
   Released v10
   https://twitter-bot-sohail.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: Do you have a `package.json` that includes the `twit` module?

Comment: Yes sir i do have.

Comment: Do you have to manually run `npm install` on Heroku or is that automatic?

Comment: I followed a video by The coding Train (Youtube Channel) I do the same not code just process. I think Heroku Does that Automaticall depned on that Procfile

Comment: Sir please help i got stuck on this problem for more than 1 week

Comment: Can you add the build log of the application to the question? Heroku Dashboard > Open the app's page > Activity > View build log (Of the latest build) I'll help you to solve this issue.

Comment: Sir I have added please check that and help me!